# Autowiring an Interface fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and Spring Integration in my application.

VendorService is my Interface whose implementation is taken care of by Spring Integration.

I am injecting VendorService's instance into my Controller by Autowiring it.

Here is my Controller..

```
@Autowired(required=true)
@Qualifier("vendorService")
VendorService vendorService;
```

I am getting the following error,

> No qualifying bean of type [com.sample.service.VendorService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=vendorService)}

Comment: do you have any implementation of `VendorService` in your application? how spring will implement it for you? It's you who will provide the implementation and spring will autowire it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not applying @Service or @Repository Annotations in your implementation class of interface (VenderService).

try this :-

```
@Repository
pulblic class VenderServiceImpl implements VenderService{
     // Do your job here.
}
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: Should link to documentation

Answer (score 1):

Spring can't find class which implements VenderService interface. Help him by adding @Service or @Component annotation to your class which implements VenderService.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that Spring could not find an implementation of `VendorService` to satisfy your autowiring request. It can only use classes that implement the specified interface to do this, and they must either be defined in a context file, or found by package scanning (through the use of an annotation).

Answer (score 0):

Here is good article on how spring loads beans in application context. Either you can manually define that as a bean using

1) `<bean id="" class=""> in application context.`

or if you want to annotate your calss then you have to add auto scanning of component using

2)`<context:component-scan base-package="XX.XX" />.`

This error occurs when spring can't find bean id in application context.

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/